Hide a field in a repeating instruments in different events
I have a Yes/No field that I want to hide in subsequent visits if "Yes" is selected during any visit.
For example, if "Yes" is selected during Visit 4, the question should be hidden in all subsequent visits, but it should remain visible in all previous visits completed.
I am aware of the Action Tag @HIDDEN, but I am having trouble implementing it correctly.
Could anyone provide guidance on how to achieve this functionality?
Instrument: Follow_up
**Field: ** [flup_relapse]
Events: from [visit_1_arm_1] to [visit_10_arm_1]
Thanks,
With the logics I have tried, I have not been able to make the questions visible in the previous visits.Here I share an attempt at logic:
@IF([visit_2_arm_1][flup_relapse]='1',@HIDDEN([visit_3_arm_1][flup_relapse]) and @HIDDEN([visit_4_arm_1][flup_relapse]) and @HIDDEN([visit_5_arm_1][flup_relapse]) and @HIDDEN([visit_6_arm_1][flup_relapse]) and @HIDDEN([visit_7_arm_1][flup_relapse]) and  @HIDDEN([visit_8_arm_1][flup_relapse]) and @HIDDEN([visit_9_arm_1][flup_relapse]) and @HIDDEN([visit_10_arm_1][flup_relapse]),"")

You can accomplish this with multiple chained if statements:
@IF([visit_1_arm_1][flup_relapse]=1 and [event-number] > 1, @HIDDEN,
@IF([visit_2_arm_1][flup_relapse]=1 and [event-number] > 2, @HIDDEN, 
@IF([visit_3_arm_1][flup_relapse]=1 and [event-number] > 3, @HIDDEN, 
@IF([visit_4_arm_1][flup_relapse]=1 and [event-number] > 4, @HIDDEN, 
@IF([visit_5_arm_1][flup_relapse]=1 and [event-number] > 5, @HIDDEN, 
@IF([visit_6_arm_1][flup_relapse]=1 and [event-number] > 6, @HIDDEN, 
@IF([visit_7_arm_1][flup_relapse]=1 and [event-number] > 7, @HIDDEN, 
@IF([visit_8_arm_1][flup_relapse]=1 and [event-number] > 8, @HIDDEN, 
@IF([visit_9_arm_1][flup_relapse]=1 and [event-number] > 9, @HIDDEN, 
    "")))))))))

This code hides the field for a given event if there was a "Yes" in any previous event.
